File not found or no read permission when trying to compress zip
On Windows 11, when I right click a folder and then choose Compress to Zip file, I get error. Although it makes no sense to close all programs that use this folder, I did close everything and nothing is referencing any files in the folder but still get the error. On Linux or Unix it wouldn't matter if any files are open, you can still read and zip everything. What is the problem on Windows?


You can try other alternative applications: (7z, WinRar, etc). https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

@Mr.Key7 oh yeah just tried out winrar it works with this tool. thanks! so i guess the Compress Archive default zip tool is outdated.
